# How to check if the set variable has a file assigned to it with the help of if condition

Tags: shell, centos, scripting, csh

```
#!/bin/csh -fx

set my_path = "/cd/home/dir"
cd $my_path
set path1 = `ls -1 | grep "abc" | head -1`
set path2 = `ls -1 | grep "def" | head -1`
```

1)#how to check if path1 has a dir assigned to it

```
if(-d $path1)then #this checks if the variable is defined but I want to check if it has a dir assigned?
 #some function
else
endif

 
if(-d $path2)then
#execute
else
endif
```

In my case `path1` and `path2` is not created every time, Either `path1` or `path2` will be created and when I run this I am getting as mentioned below. eg:- path2 is not created
`if: Missing file name.`

If it is not created or missing file name then it should go to endif.
Kindly help

Comment: mmh, yeah, can you check the formatting? I'm not sure if I got your code blocks right. They're described as the very first item in the editing help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of quoting the expansion? `-d "$path2"`

Comment: It worked by quoting the expression thanks a ton. I am invoking a perl script from  c shell script in order to send an email by passing the arguments which includes my email address but I am unable to receive an email and throws an error:                                             Unable to read file                                                                                                                No recipient addresses found in header. Kindly suggest on what can be done